# How to loop mouse clicks if left mouse button is held down

Tags: c++

i am trying to make an autoclicker. It should repeat MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN and MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP when LBUTTON is held.

Here is what i have so far. it doesn't repeat it, it double clicks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>
using namespace std;

void menu()
{
    cout << "Press 'F4' to enable and 'F5' to disable autoclicker\n";
}

void clicker()
{
    bool click = false;

    while (true)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState('X'))
        {
            click = true;
        }

        else if (GetAsyncKeyState('Z'))
        {
            click = false;
        }

        if (click == true)
        {
                while (GetKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
                {
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                    Sleep(100);
                }   
        }

    }
}

int main()
{
    menu();
    clicker();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated! thanks

Comment: `mouse_event()` is deprecated, use `SendInput()` instead. Also, what if the mouse button is down and `click` is false, shouldn't the code release the mouse button?

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving the target application enough time to detect the key press, you should be using SendInput() as it's not deprecated.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

INPUT LeftButton = { 0 };
LeftButton.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
LeftButton.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
SendInput(1, &LeftButton, sizeof(INPUT));

std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));

LeftButton.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
SendInput(1, &LeftButton, sizeof(INPUT));
```